# Question on UIApplicationDelegate generated by Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying on objective-C and Xcode 4, and get some bit I don't understand. 
The following code are generated by the Xcode for a view-based iphone application:

In the .h file:

```
@interface viewexampleAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet viewexampleViewController *viewController;
@end
```

In the .m file:

```
@synthesize window=_window;
@synthesize viewController=_viewController;
```

So the question is: 
where is the _window and _viewController comes from? I didn't see any declaration or initialization of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C allows declaring properties without having to explicitly declare the corresponding backing instance variables. Instead, instance variables are synthesized as needed. In this case, by default the name of the backing instance variable is the same as the declared property name. So, assuming the class hasn’t declared an instance variable called `something`,

```
@synthesize something;
```

would implicitly create an instance variable also called `something`.

It is also possible to have the instance variable be named differently from the declared property, e.g.

```
@synthesize something = _something;
```

The compiler then creates a backing instance variable called `_something` in case one doesn’t already exist.

With regard to initialisation, both properties are `IBOutlets`. This usually means that their corresponding instances are loaded from a nib file, and the nib file has outlets connecting those properties to actual objects.